# stucked do loop in fortran

Tags: fortran, do-loops

i just make easy equation(gaussian-plume eq.)
the goal is Concentration values based on x, y, z distribution
but the loop is stucked at just first step what's the problem?
here's my code

```
  PROGRAM plume
  IMPLICIT NONE
  REAL,PARAMETER :: pi=3.141592, q=1000, u=5, t=10,
 &                  kx=1, ky=1, kz=1
  REAL :: d, dx, dy, dz, f1, f2, C
  INTEGER :: x, y, z

  OPEN(10, file='./results/plume.txt')

  WRITE(10,'(3(A4),2(x,A50))') "x","y","z", "f2", "C"

  dy = dx
  dz = dx
  dx = (2 * kx * t)

  PRINT*, "f1=", f1(q,pi,u,dx)

  DO x = 0, 1000, 10
   DO y = -500,500,10 
    DO z = 0,500,10 
     f2 = exp( -(1/2) * ( ( (y**2.) + (z**2.) ) / dx ) ) 
     C = f1(q,pi,u,dx) * f2
     WRITE(10,'(3(I4),(x,2(F50.48)))') x, y, z, f2, C
    END DO
   END DO
  END DO
     

  END PROGRAM


  FUNCTION f1(q,pi,u,dx)
  IMPLICIT NONE
  REAL :: q, pi, u
  REAL :: f1, dx
   f1 = q / (2 * pi * u * dx)
  END FUNCTION f1
```

Comment: The order of the three initialization statements for `dy`, `dz`, and `dz` looks incorrect.  Not sure if that is causing your problem, but you are referencing `dx` before it has been assigned a value.

Comment: `1/2` is zero in your exponentiation. You are also not allowed to evaluate `(-500)**2.`.

Comment: wow thx for comment it solved

Comment: Looking deeper at your code `f2` is always equal to 1.  The value of `(1/2)` is zero, because you are dividing the integer `1` by the value `2`.   Also, it would be better to use integer exponents in `(y**2.)`, that is, change `2.` to simply `2`.

Comment: This line is likely wrong `c = f1(q, pi, u, dx) * f2`.  You want `x` not `dx`.